# How to save HTML table form as a json field with Rails 5.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

In order to add more or less structured annotations to the ValuesList object, I added a JSON type field named 'anything' to the Postgres table. I also added :anything to ValuesListController strong parameters.

To input the annotations data, I created a dynamic table of input fields with JavaScript. The view correctly sends back the input data, but I don't know how to process it:

**I receive a hash, but don't know how to format it for the JSON field.**

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
<div id="jsonTable-container">
  <div id="jsonTable">
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  (function($) {

      var jsonData = <%= raw this_object.anything.to_json %>;

      // Get table header
      if (!jsonData) {
        var columns = ['Indice', 'Type', 'Title',   'Text'];
      } else {
        var columns = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
          for (var key in jsonData[i]) {
            if (columns.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              columns.push(key);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(columns)

      // Create the table
      var table = $('<table/>', {class: 'table'});

      // Create columns headers
      var tr = $('<tr/>').appendTo(table);
      for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        var th = $('<th/>').appendTo(tr);
        th.html(columns[i]);
      }

      // Add lines to the table if data available
      if (jsonData) {
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
          var tr = $('<tr/>').appendTo(table);
          for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
            var td = $('<td/>').appendTo(tr);
            var fieldIndex = ('anything').concat('[', (i).toString(), '][', columns[j],']');
            $('<input>').attr({
              name: fieldIndex,
              id: fieldIndex,
              type: 'text',
              value: jsonData[i][columns[j]]
            }).appendTo(td);
          }
        }
      }

      // Add the table to jsonTable-container
      var tableContainer = $("#jsonTable");
      tableContainer.html("");
      tableContainer.append(table);

  }(jQuery));
</script>
```

The sample JSON data:

```
[{"Indice": "1","Type": "ABBREV","Title": "ShortName","Text": "UNDEF"},{"Indice": "2","Type": "ALIAS","Title": "AliasName","Text": "UNKOWN"},{"Indice": "3","Type": "ALIAS","Title": "FemaleName","Text": "UNDEFINED"}]
```

generates the following HTML table form:

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Indice</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Text</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="anything[0][Indice]" id="anything[0][Indice]" type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input name="anything[0][Type]" id="anything[0][Type]" type="text" value="ABBREV"></td>
      <td><input name="anything[0][Title]" id="anything[0][Title]" type="text" value="ShortName"></td>
      <td><input name="anything[0][Text]" id="anything[0][Text]" type="text" value="UNDEF"></td>
    </tr>
Etc.
```

The resulting paramter received upon form submition is:

```
params[:anything]
<ActionController::Parameters {"0"=>{"Indice"=>"1", "Type"=>"ABBREV", "Title"=>"ShortName", "Text"=>"UNDEF"}, "1"=>{"Indice"=>"2", "Type"=>"ALIAS", "Title"=>"AliasName", "Text"=>"UNKOWN"}, "2"=>{"Indice"=>"3", "Type"=>"ALIAS", "Title"=>"FemaleName", "Text"=>"UNDEFINED"}} permitted: false>
```

Which is saved in the target field as:

```
{"0":{"Indice":"1","Type":"ABBREV","Title":"ShortName","Text":"UNDEF"},"1":{"Indice":"2","Type":"ALIAS","Title":"AliasName","Text":"UNKOWN"},"2":{"Indice":"3","Type":"ALIAS","Title":"FemaleName","Text":"UNDEFINED"}}
```

Which is much better than the first version of this post. But how can I turn this into the original data?

Comment: Is it fine if i store the table in string and use pure js to give the table out ??

Comment: This is an interesting option. Can this be done at submition, before sending data back to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const TimeTable=function(str) {
    var results;
    days=0;
    const figureToControl=(h)=> {
        var g='';
        if ( !Number.isNaN(+h)===true) {
            Number(h);
            for(h > 0; h--; ) {
                g+='<th></th>';
            }
        }
        else {
            g=`<th>${h}</th>`;
        }
        return g
    }
    const operate=(a, c)=> {
        days++;
        results=a.push(`<tr>${c.split(',').reduce((g, h)=>(g.push(figureToControl(h)), g), []).join('')}</tr>`) 
        return results
    }
    var tableText = '';
    tableText+=str.split('/').reduce((a, c)=> (operate(a, c), a), []).join('');
    return tableText+"</table>";
}
console.log(TimeTable("1,9F,6/8/10E,9D,2,9E,10E,2/2,9F,2,9S,2/8/10E,9D,9E,2,9S,2"));
```

Here we go Let me explain How you have to input the string
If You use `/` it will warp it in `<tr>` so `1,9F,3/4` will be `<tr><th></th><th>9F</th><th></th><th></th><th></th><tr><tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>`

If You use `,` it will warp it in `<th>` so `1,9F,3` will be `<th></th><th>9F</th><th></th><th></th><th></th>`

Now numbers mean there will be a empty `<th>` so `3` will be `<th></th><th></th><th></th>`

This is pretty reliable also it returns a string and not a html elemet you can import it using
`elment.innerHTMl = tablestring` and I it also works with spaces dont worry if I didnt write your desired json string but you can always change my code